# Typescript this as a function parameter/return type

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to be able to reference the type of the current object in a function's parameter/return type, such as the following:

in `.d.ts`:

```
interface Object {
    add(object: Partial<this>): this;
}
```

in `.js`:

```
Object.prototype.add = function(object) {
    Object.assign(this, object);
}
```

The intended behavior of this function is to only allow the parameter to contain properties that are already defined on the object via `Partial<this>`. However, in attempted use such as

```
document.body.style.add({
    fontSize: "12px"
});
```

TypeScript gives me the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ fontSize: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type `Partial<Object>`.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fontSize' does not exist in type 'Partial<Object>'.
```

I assume that this is because the `this` types in my `.d.ts` actually just refers to `Object` because that's the containing interface for the function instead of recognizing the `CSSStyleDeclaration` type that `document.body.style` is. How can I achieve a function like this, that uses the type of the object it's being applied to as parameters/return type? Is this possible in TypeScript?

Comment: Well the first suggestion I'd make is to try to refrain from modifying native objects and patching their types. If you need some reasoning as to why, I'm sure you can find loads of posts about why it's not recommended to mess with the native objects.

Comment: And as for your actual question, I don't think so. You could add a generic parameter, or patch the types for whatever objects you use the method on, but those aren't really DRY.

Comment: You could get the desired behavior using a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVk5Mm), although it is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) to mess with native prototypes.  Does this fully address your question? If so, I can write up an answer explaining.  If not, what am I missing?  (Please @jcalz mention me if you reply or I won't be notified.)

Comment: @jcalz Works perfectly! Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you! If you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: it is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) to modify native prototypes this way. You may have some reason why it's okay to do this for your use cases, but you should probably avoid it. Anyway, let's move on.

---

As you noticed, [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) doesn't really work the way you want for the [native `interface` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#general-types) like `Object`, `String`, etc..  Even known subtypes of `Object` will see `this` rendered as `Object` instead of the known subtype.

As a workaround you can emulate the desired behavior by making the method [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and give it a generic [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters):

```
interface Object {
  add<T>(this: T, object: Partial<T>): T;
}
```

So now if you call `add()` on some object of type `CSSStyleDeclaration`, the type checker will infer `T` to be `CSSStyleDeclaration`, and thus expect a `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>` as its parameter.  So the following works as expected:

```
document.body.style.add({
  fontSize: "12px"
});
// (method) Object.add<CSSStyleDeclaration>(
//   this: CSSStyleDeclaration, object: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>
// ): CSSStyleDeclaration
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQHkBGArKSKoDewqqCAJuQDwAqAfABQQAWIAzgFyo0A0qA9jjwQuABQQwIIBABtadAJRcaAbmABfYMCy58AOgAOMfhBMBPA1D0VyqALyo4AVzD4Q-MKnlNWnbn0FdEVRxSWk5egUiElQYKAgnGE8dYWs2NhAAczAfdgChfAU1TWByfiQnAFsoSD1MfnIzPTYIMxkrGwZiUjgPCABlEAAvKC4AIgBGACYDAA8xjSLgAHpl1AZqlgaolP0bKgBhfuPW9oARPBkJBCkPRhW10hZ2LiOTtqgLpCuYG-cwfJBMQSKSyQ7HfqnT6Xa63MB0B6oJSoN6Qj5fH5-DxaJAeNj8dp6GT8TIMMoVaq1eqNZpQvS9SCDEZRVaoSYzeZAA)